# Assign disk space from one partition to a non-consecutive partition on the same disk

Tags: disk-utility, partition

My external hard drive `ExtDisk` is set up as follows (output from `diskutil list`):

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Foo                     1.0 TB     disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Foo2                    50.0 GB    disk2s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS DELETE_ME               100.0 GB   disk2s8
   5:                  Apple_HFS Foo3                    600.0 GB   disk2s4
   6:                  Apple_HFS Foo4                    150.0 GB   disk2s5
   7:                  Apple_HFS MERGE_HERE              100.0 GB   disk2s6
```

I'm trying to take the disk space currently allocated to `DELETE_ME` and add it to `MERGE_HERE`, deleting `DELETE_ME` in the process. Disk Utility, representing this list in pie chart format, automatically adds freed space from a partition to the previous partition on the list — in this case, that would mean merging `DELETE_ME` into `Foo2` instead of `MERGE_HERE`.

I *could* manually move the data from `Foo2` to `DELETE_ME`, resize, and repeat, working my way through the list until I move the free space adjacent to and merged with `MERGE_HERE`, but that's incredibly time-consuming.

Is there a way to do this, if not with Disk Utility then with Terminal? MacOS is running Catalina 10.15.7, and Terminal is running zsh. My external disk is partitioned with GUID.

Comment: If you are willing to accept a command line solution, then you probably should have included the output from `diskutil list`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Done.

Comment: Since resizing a HFS partition does not change where the partition starts, I do not understand what would be gained by manually moving the data from `Foo2` to `DELETE_ME`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson If the free space is in `Foo` I can easily merge `Foo` into `MERGE_HERE`. By manually reshuffling the data and resizing I can move all the extra free space into `Foo` and delete that instead of `DELETE_ME`.

Comment: You are aware that the other `Apple_HFS` partitions do not move, when a partition is deleted or resize to create free space, Also, the `diskutil list` command does not show where this free space between partitions exists. You need to use the `gpt` command or a third party command such as `driveinfo`, if you what to see where the free space between partitions resides.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I don't know whether I'm using the right terminology; I'm not referring to free space that exists outside of any partition, but rather the space currently occupied by an empty partition that I want to allocate to a different one.